# Using execv() with PATH env variable

Tags: c, unix, exec

I'm writing a shell and I want to use [execv()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html) and search for the right directory through the `$PATH` environment variable (Yes, I know I can use `execvp()` and just pass the name of the file to it).

What I'm thinking about doing is getting a string from `getenv("PATH")`, breaking it down to separate paths then trying each one. But I was wondering if there is an easier way to do it?

I guess the question is: how does `execvp()` search for the right path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you described is exactly how `execvp()` searches the PATH. I don't think there's much point in reimplementing this yourself.